# bibligraphy style: aligning text in bibliography items

Tags: bibliographies, vertical-alignment, bibliographystyle

I'm writing my thesis but I have a problem with the alignment of lines in the bibliography items, as shown in the photo below:

[image]

I want all lines of bibliography items to line up with the blue line.

I'm using bibliographic style `abntex2-num` recommended by my university. I need to change something in the bibliographic style code but I don't know how.

The document is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\begin{document}

Citations \cite{lotfalian1985inertial}, \cite{liu2009application}, \cite{stott1974fast}  and \cite{tinney1967power}

\bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
\bibliography{referencias}

\end{document}
```

The file with bibliographic style abntex2-num.bst is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13TB9xOun_wbuVffIxA0dxqDL5nXHWARd/view?usp=sharing).

The file with the references `referencias.bib` are:

```
@article{lotfalian1985inertial,
    title={Inertial, governor, and AGC/economic dispatch load flow simulations of loss of generation contingencies},
    author={Lotfalian, M and Schlueter, R and Idizior, D and Rusche, P and Tedeschi, S and Shu, L and Yazdankhah, A},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems},
    number={11},
    volume={PAS-104},
    pages={3020--3028},
    year={1985},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{liu2009application,
    title={Application of the power flow calculation method to islanding micro grids},
    author={Liu, YH and Wu, ZQ and Lin, SJ and Brandon, NP},
    conference={{INTERNATIONAL CONFERENCE ON SUSTAINABLE POWER GENERATION AND SUPPLY}},
    pages={1--6},
    cyear={2009},
    ctitle={Proceedings [...]}, 
    caddress={Nanjing}
}

@article{stott1974fast,
    title={Fast decoupled load flow},
    author={Stott, Brian and Alsac, Of},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems},
    volume={PAS-93},
    number={3},
    month=may,
    pages={859--869},
    year={1974}
} 

@article{tinney1967power,
    title={Power flow solution by Newton's method},
    author={Tinney, William F and Hart, Clifford E},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems},
    volume={PAS-86},
    number={11},
    month=Nov,
    pages={1449--1460},
    year={1967},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
```

I need a solution that changes a few lines of code within the bibliographic style file.

How can I change some lines in bibliographic style code to correct formatting?

Comment: That seems to be by design in that `.bst` file. The generated `thebibliography` env has an argument to control this indentation. But the `.bst` (I looked at the one in TeXLive 2021 as I don't like going to external sites, note that external links rot over time) uses `\begin{thebibliography}{}`

Comment: Have you tried `\setlength\bibindent{2em}` (or however much the hanging indentation is supposed to be)?

Comment: @mico I tried and it didn't work

Comment: @daleif Do you know any command I can use inside ```\begin{thebibliography}``` , in the generated ```.bbl``` file? I thought about modifying it but I don't know how.